# React render - Infinite loop happenes sometimes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I have a simple login component which works fine (i.e it redirects to dashboard most of the times after successful login). However, sometimes out of blue, it throws an error:

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
> repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
> componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
> prevent infinite loops.

Here're my code.
Please note that when the error happnens, I notice, `<Redirect to={routes.DASHBOARD}/>` this gets called, but instead of redirecting to this component, the same login component keeps getting called infinitely.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { login } from '../../redux/actions';
import styles from './login.module.css';
import {routes} from '../../routes';

export function Login() {
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [email, setEmail] =useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const handleLogin = ()=>{
      dispatch(login({email, password}))
  }

  const handleEmailInput = (e)=>{
      setEmail(e.target.value)
  }

  const handlePasswordInput = (e)=>{
      setPassword(e.target.value)
  }

  if((user.tokenReceived || localStorage.getItem('token')) && !user.tokenExpired){
    return <Redirect to={routes.DASHBOARD}/>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.row}>

          <input type='text' placeholder="Email" onChange={handleEmailInput}/>
          <input type='text' placeholder="Password" onChange={handlePasswordInput}/>

        <button
          className={styles.loginButton}
          onClick={handleLogin}
        >
          Login
        </button>
        {user.error && "Some Error occurred. Please try again"}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing the right way, but should I be wrapping this under `useEffect`,

```
if((user.tokenReceived || localStorage.getItem('token')) && !user.tokenExpired){
    return <Redirect to={routes.DASHBOARD}/>
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide code of your login action?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus I didn;t want to make it too verbose, so didn't put it here. But if that's relevant to you, you can take a look at it here:
https://github.com/wickedrahul/react-app-gateway/blob/main/my-app/src/redux/actions/login.js

Comment: After looking at your code a bit. You have 2 sources of truth for checking login. So if token is not saved properly in localStorage your Dashboard returns you back to login since there you are checking only for localStorage token. And on login page you accept either from store or localStorage.

So imagine situation where you have token in your redux store but not saved in localStorage. Login component would redirect to Dashboard and vice-versa.

I would check that first

Comment: @MarioNikolaus I see your point. Let me try that. Thanks

Comment: @MarioNikolaus I made it this way:

``` if((localStorage.getItem('token')) && !user.tokenExpired){
    return <Redirect to={routes.DASHBOARD}/>
  }``` On Login

```if(!savedToken || tokenExpired){
    return <Redirect to={routes.LOGIN}/>
  }``` On Dashboard,

But I'm still seeing the error.

Comment: What does your stack trace say? Is it happening on Login page or somewhere else?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus Found the error. What actually happens is, Login component redirects to Dashbboard, however, in App.js it checks whether the user is authenticated or not (by seeing the localstorage). At this time the localstorage is not set. Hence App.js redirects back to Login and to and fro continues. 
That also explains why the redirection to dashboard wasn't happening
 Phew! Pretty nasty one. Thanks for your inputs. If you care to put this into answer, I'll upvote.

Comment: No need, I wasn't checking the App code at all! Good that you've found it. But yeah, generally single source of truth is a way to simplify your life :D

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lays when you call handleLogin function on button click. Call the function as an arrow function.

```
<button
     className={styles.loginButton}
     onClick={() => handleLogin()}
>
```

Comment: handleLogin as is is a callback itself, so I don't see why this would be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you update a state, the page is re-rendered. It means that every time you update a state, this `if` is called.

Use a UseEffect to validate data when user just access the page.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if((user.tokenReceived || localStorage.getItem('token')) && !user.tokenExpired){
    return <Redirect to={routes.DASHBOARD}/>
  } 
}, [])
```